# Boton atras adentro de la Camara

Tags: android, botón, back

**Buen día tengo una duda que llevo días sin resolver ando haciendo una aplicacion pero quiero poner un boton externo donde se visualiza adentro de la camara pero no hago que se regrese al menu anterior.(boton regreso) soy muy bueno con el diseño en si, para la programacion soy pesimo si les interesa intercambio de trabajo por sus conocimientos programacion, hazmelo saber! :)**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Boton de retroceso Capture.XML

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginVertical="320dip"
        android:background="@drawable/retrocesobtn"
        android:rotation="270"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:text="retroceso"
        />
```

Capture Activity

```
 public final class CaptureActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback,
        ShutterButton.OnShutterButtonListener {
     
Button button2;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.capture);

      button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent button2 = new Intent(CaptureActivity.this, CalculatorActivity.class);
                startActivity(button2);

            }
        });

    }


    }
```

Es un app ya desarollada nomas que ando agregando varias cosas ya investigue pero no lo hago que cambie de pantalla no se si tengo que cambiar el activity, AYUDA!

Comment: Pues, lo único que deberías hacer es cerrar la cámara

Comment: Es para regresar a una nueva ventana que tiene una calculadora, pero no lo hago regresar en el boton y aparezca la ventana de la calculadora , ya lo intente en lo convencional para cambiar de un layout a otro pero sin resultados..

Comment: Ya lo resolvi cambiandolo de java a codigo kotlin y poniendolo asi en el android manifest.xml      activity android:name=".listo"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"/> agrege nadamas el android theme dentro del activity